# Git No remote branches

Tags: git, netbeans

I am trying to close a git reposotory into my netbeans.

I did Team->Git->clone

I set the repository url and all , push next , and than there are no branches to select from.

How do i add a branch to select from?

Comment: I found that with netbeans 7.0.1 the issue happens even if the remote branches are there. I just uninstalled the old version of netbeans and installed netbeans 8.0 and now I am getting the list of all remote branches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds to me like your remote repository is empty.  Your best bet is to create a local repository, using Initialize (*Team → Git → Initialize*) instead of Clone.  After you do some work and add a commit, you should be able to push to the remote repository, which will create the new branch.

I tried doing this process in Netbeans, which wasn't too bad.  I'd recommend learning to use Git from the command line, if you haven't tried though.  The GUI still needs some work, and it failed to add the .gitignore to the repository.  However, it did all work and was relatively straight-forward.

Comment: My remote repository is not empty but, it still shows remote branches.